# Python dictionaries Filtering stuff out

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I'm working on class lab and I'm kind of stuck, for example I have a dictionary with key and value which is another dictionary.

Dictionary A:

```
dict_a = {
    1: {
        'Engine': 4,
        'Speed': 749,
        'max_speed': 1140,
        'name': 'Ship1',
    },

    2: {
        'Engine': 2,
        'Speed': 600,
        'max_speed': 900,
        'name': 'B777',
    },

    3: {
        'Engine': 4,
        'Speed': 1130,
        'max_speed': 1200,
        'name': 'Air_max',
    }
}
```

I am trying to write an function which will take two argument (Dictionary A, and a Filter Dictionary) For example:

```
filter = {
    'Engine' :4,
    'name': 'Air_max',
}
```

This function should return a list with dictionaries that has value > or equal to filter:

This is just an example. As i just need an Hint idea how to do this. In reality my Dictionary A is very big.

So far i have this which does not looking right:

```
filtered = {
    'Engine':   2,
    'Speed':  300,
    'Type': 'Electric'
}

result = []
for k, v in full_data.items():
    for i, s in v.items():
        for a, b in filtered.items():
            if v[i] >= filtered[a]:
                result.append(v)
filtered_result = []
for each in result:
    if each not in filtered_result:
        filtered_result.append(each)
filtered_result[:3]
```

Comment: It looks like your "dictionary" defeats the purpose of dictionaries, if you have to iterate over them.

Comment: It seems like you want a `list` of `dict`s and not a `dict` of `dict`s where the keys are basically just indexes.

Comment: What's the problem with your filtering code? Does it not work at all? Is it too slow? What kind of results does it produce?

Comment: @Blurp I'm getting back list of dictionaries, not filtered.

Comment: @MooingRawr No  i do not want a code back, i just want what i'm doing wrong. and how to fix it.

Comment: @user3035168 when I posted that comment you didn't show what you've tried (ie your code). I'm glad you edited your question to put your code back in with proper format :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, this part seems to be a bit of a mess:

```
for k, v in full_data.items():
    for i, s in v.items():
        for a, b in filtered.items():
            if v[i] >= filtered[a]:
                result.append(v)
```

The `k`, `v` identifiers are terrific, brief and idiomatic. The `i`, `s` ones, less so. And I suspect you meant `filter` when you wrote `filtered`. Anyway, I urge you to write a helper function, a predicate `is_wanted(data, filter)` that returns True when filter criteria are satisfied. You will be able to test the helper function separately from your loop.

Then return to your loop which will now call the predicate, and consider giving more descriptive names to your variables. Overall you appear to be on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
filter = {
'Engine' :4,
'name': 'Air_max',
}
new_dict_a = [{a:b} for a, b in dict_a.items() if b['Engine'] >= filter['Engine']]
```

Output:

```
[{1: {'Engine': 4, 'max_speed': 1140, 'Speed': 749, 'name': 'Ship1'}}, {3: {'Engine': 4, 'max_speed': 1200, 'Speed': 1130, 'name': 'Air_max'}}]
```

If you want a dictionary instead of a list:

```
new_dict_a = {a:b for a, b in dict_a.items() if b['Engine'] >= filter['Engine']}
```

Output:

```
{1: {'Engine': 4, 'max_speed': 1140, 'Speed': 749, 'name': 'Ship1'}, 3: {'Engine': 4, 'max_speed': 1200, 'Speed': 1130, 'name': 'Air_max'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if filter dic is not fixed, I mean it's up to uses to provide keys and values of dic. And user may choose to skip Engine.  And can just filter buy into values.